# Using a dynamic type in an editable Kendo UI Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, dynamictype

I'm currently working on a project, where I need to create a Grid with columns chosen by the user. These columns can originate from arbitrary tables in the database context. To make things worse the database is managed by a different software, and tables and table fields can change frequently. This will not change in the forseeable future.

So I can't just create a model, that contains all possible columns. Instead I'm using the `dynamic` type to hand the data over to the view. This works quite good with every option I added to the Kendo Grid - except for making it editable. To make the example easier to understand I left out everything not relevant (like `.Sortable()` or the method to read data via Ajax)

`ColumnData[]` is an array of all columns displayed, containing their type and name

```
@model ColumnData[]
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<dynamic>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++)
            {
                columns.Bound(Model[i].Type, Model[i].Name);
            }
        })
        //.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
        )
)
```

This works as intended until I uncomment the `.Editable` part. Then it throws an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property
    access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions
```

My guess is, that it uses a lamba function somewhere, which cannot be used with dynamic objects. I have no idea, how I could get around this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since making the grid editable at runtime is not possible ([see here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/change-grid-editable-at-runtime)) I think you should initialise the entire grid on the client side.
You can find a good example example [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline).

Comment: I'll keep that possibility at the back of my mind, but I didn't really want to switch to creating the grid in js, for maintainability reasons mainly. (We don't have much custom js code and would like to keep it that way)